# CRM 2011 - How to update Marketing List Member Type options to reflect entity display name changes?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there a way of updating the Option Set options for the Marketing List Member Type to reflect an entity display name change? i.e. if the account entity has been renamed to organisation, is there a supported way of reflecting this in the displayed options? I have been able to achieve this using javascript, but wondered if there was a better way of achieving this? At the moment I am unable to change the descriptions of the current options: Account, Contact or Lead.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution..

Create a Solution in your crm org. Add Marketing list to it.
Export the translations from the solution and when you open the translation excel file you will see all 3 picklist values.

from there you can change the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to rename an existing entity, you should also rename its 'messages'.

You will find them in the customization area. Open the entity account. There you will find 'messages'. These are the strings which are used for the entity.

For a complete renaming, you have to replace the term 'account' in these messages.

Comment: Hi ckeller, thanks for your response. I have updated the account message string for the account entity from 'Account' to 'Organisation' and published the changes, but when I go to add a marketing list, the member type is still displaying as 'Account'? Do I need to update anything on the list entity? I have seen another system where the Member Type option set descriptions have been updated to reflect a name change from 'Account' to 'Organisation', but I don't know how this was achieved. Is there something I am missing or could try? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a normal Option Set on the Marketing List entity called "createdfromcode" which has three options (Account, Contact, Lead) and the underlying values match the entity type codes (1,2,4).

You can't edit this option set directly, but you could set up your own with appropriate values and the labels you want to use, add that option set to the form and use javascript to copy the selected value into the existing field (which you keep on the form but not visible).